# MySQL one to many with primary choice

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Say I have a bunch of people with multiple phone numbers. In a MySQL database I'd have a Person table and a Phone Number table with a many to one relationship.
Now I want to make one of those numbers the primary phone number and only allow one primary number per person. How would I model this?

Comment: didn't clear your requirements ?

Comment: How do you figure out which duplicate rows for the phone number to be removed ? If you can figure that out, all you need to do is make phone number as primary key (after removal of duplicate data offcourse)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the schema below.  It will prevent entries that try to assign more than one primary number per person.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE phonenumber (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phonenumber` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `is_primary` ENUM('1'),
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY idx_person_primary (`person_id`, `is_primary`),
  UNIQUE KEY idx_person_phone (`phonenumber`, `person_id`)
);   

INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Michael', 'Jones');
INSERT INTO phonenumber (phonenumber, person_id, is_primary) VALUES ('9876543210', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO phonenumber (phonenumber, person_id, is_primary) VALUES ('1234567890', 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO phonenumber (phonenumber, person_id, is_primary) VALUES ('1234567891', 1, NULL);
```

This will allow the DB to police a single primary phone number for each person.  For example if you try to assign another primary phone number to Michael Jones:

INSERT INTO phonenumber (phonenumber, person_id, is_primary) VALUES ('0123211234', 1, 1);

You will get a "Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'idx_person_primary'" error.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbb3c7/1

Comment: Are you sure that this solution allow you to have more than 2 numbers?

Comment: Note that this is depending on a kludge:  namely that a `UNIQUE` key can have multiple rows with `NULL` (in `is_primary`).

Comment: @RickJames wouldn't declaring `is_primary` as `NOT NULL` do the trick?

Comment: @Billzabob - If you make it `NOT NULL`, then it will be forced to have a value.  For `ENUM` it will be the _first_ option, namely `1`.  Oops -- Now all entries will be `1` and you will have duplicates!

Answer (score 1):

The "exactly one primary phone number" is tricky.  One way uses triggers.  Other databases offer expression-based indexes.  This is tricky because:

- The constraint spans two tables.
- Guaranteeing exact "one-ness" across updates is tricky.

But one method in MySQL that comes close and doesn't use triggers:

```
create table persons (
    personId int auto_increment primary key,
    primary_personPhonesId int,
    . . .
);

create table personPhones (
    personPhonesId int auto_increment primary key,
    personId int,
    . . .
    foreign key (personId) references persons (personId),
    unique (personId, personPhonesId)  -- seems redundant but needed
);

alter table persons
    add foreign key (personId, primary_personPhonesId) on personPhones(personId, personPhonesId);
```

It is tempting to declare `primary_personPhonesId` as `not null`.  However, that makes it difficult to insert rows into the two tables.

An alternative method uses computed columns:

```
create table persons (
    personId int auto_increment primary key,
    . . .
);

create table personPhones (
    personPhonesId int auto_increment primary key,
    personId int,
    isPrimary boolean,
    . . .
    foreign key (personId) references persons (personId),
    primaryId as (case when isPrimary then personPhonesId end),
    unique(primaryId)
);
```

Similar to the previous solution, this does not guarantee that `isPrimary` is always set.

Comment: Genome's and Strawberry's `UNIQUE(person_id, is_primary)` solves the "exactly one primary"

Comment: I should've been more specific, but for me not having a primary number is acceptable. It also makes it easier to change primary numbers by disabling the primary number then enabling another.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below mentioned design:

```
Person (Id (PK),name,....)
TelephoneNumber (Id(PK), telNo, PersonId(FK))
PrimaryTelNo (PersonId(FK), TelId(FK))
```

You can create a table showing mapping of  `TelId` and `PersonId` and declare the combination of `TelId` and `PersonId` as `composite primary key`

Comment: Couldn't this lead to a scenario where the primary number points to one person, but the number it points to points to a different person? Is there a way to make sure this doesn't happen? Also I don't think you'd want the composite primary key behavior, just have Person as the primary key. Otherwise you could have multiple entries for one person as long as the numbers are different, which means multiple primary phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a third table `person_primary_number` with only two fields:

```
person_id
phone_number_id
```

In this table you should insert the ids of the person and his primary number. The primary key of this table is on these two columns.

Another way is to add `primary_number_id` directly to the `person` table. This is probably the simplest solution.

Then you should have:

```
person
—————-
id (primary key int autoincrement)
primary_number_id (foreign key for phone_number.id)
name
... 

phone_number
———————————-
id (primary key int autoincrement)
person_id (foreign key for person.id)
phone_number
```

The only problem with this solution is that you can assign as primary phone the number of somebody else.

Comment: @RickJames that's only two tables. I think that's probably the minimum you could have for this problem. It's a simple solution but the flaw kik points out is a scenario I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: @Billzabob - Oops, I missed your paragraph "Another way...".  Removing my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make the 'first' one primary, but this becomes tricky when you want to change which one is primary. In that case, I believe you can do this...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(person_id INT NOT NULL
,phone VARCHAR(12) not null
,is_primary enum('1') null 
,primary key(person_id,phone)
, unique (person_id,is_primary)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'123',1),
(1,'234',null),
(1,'345',null),
(2,'456',null),
(2,'567',1),
(2,'678',null);
```

So, the enum allows values of 1 and null, but while there can be several nulls, there can only be one '1' per person. However, this solution doesn't preclude the possibility that none of the numbers are primary!

Comment: For my particular scenario it's fine if none are primary. This seems like the best solution although it makes me uncomfortable and seems slightly hacky to me...

Answer (score 0):

This violates a strong principle of schema design -- don't pack a list into a cell.  But...

- If you only need to display the phone number to some human who will be doing a call, and
- If that human possibly needs to see non-primary numbers, then

Consider having a `VARCHAR(100)` column that has a commalist that starts with the 'primary' phone number and continues with alternative numbers.

Note that the application would be responsible for putting the list together, and dealing with updates.  Or you could push this back onto the user by providing a UI that asks for "phone number(s), starting with the preferred one to call you with; please separate with commas."